# Logging ping results python?

Tags: python, logging, ping

I can use the ping command and save the output using the following line:

```
command = os.system('ping 127.0.0.1 > new.txt')
```

However each time the script is run the text file is overwritten so I only have the last ping saved. I have looked into logging but cannot find a way to save the outputs of the ping requests into a text file without over writing.

I have tried:

```
logging.debug(command = os.system('ping 127.0.0.1'))
```

But this throws up an error with: debug() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried `command = os.system('ping 127.0.0.1 >> new.txt')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get result of subprocess.check_output and write it to a file:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(['ping', '127.0.0.1'])
with open("new.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `os.system`, then simply use `>>` redirection:

```
command = os.system('ping 127.0.0.1 >> new.txt')
```

This would append new data to `new.txt` instead of overwriting it.

Another solution is to use `subprocess` module and manage file handler manually. This has the advantage of skipping the shell (it's faster and in some cases safer):

```
import subprocess
out = open('new.txt', 'a')
subprocess.call(['ping', '127.0.0.1'], stdout = out)
out.close()
```

Notice that you can do something else with `stdout`. For example, save it to string.

Comment: Thanks, what would you recommend over using os.system?

Comment: It's fine if os.system solution works for you. But I still edited the answer with subprocess solution.

Comment: The subprocess example above overwrites the text file even though I have used 'a' with: out = open('new.txt', 'a')

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it on my system (Mac). File is appended. That said, I think @noSkill solution is better than mine. At least until the output is small enough not to eat the memory. Still, upvote all of us :)

Comment: Yeah, it definitely over writes! Thanks for the help though!